# Real-time draw.lines using serial port data

Tags: c#, winforms, plot, serial-port, drawing

I want my simple program to take X and Y coordinates from serial port and draw them in window (like paint but with other device than mouse).
I managed to create code that recive and transforms data however I can't handle drawing that data on form.

Program works until Form1 window shows up. Then i recieve only "data_recived" and data value in console but rest of the datarecived event don't execute.

I know it is something wrong with DataReceivedHandler but i tried so many solution and none of them worked. (in comments you can see my attempts to use timer trigerred event to do that).

Could anyone give me at least some tips how to solve my problem? I would be really grateful

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    public string data;
    private List<Point> points; 

    private Bitmap bmp; 
    private Pen pen;
    private PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

    //private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    //private DateTime _startTime;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        DoubleBuffered = true; 

        pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        points = new List<Point>();

      //  _startTime = DateTime.Now;
       // _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100); // 0.1 s
       // _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler (timer_Elapsed);
       // _timer.Start();
      //  Console.WriteLine("Czas Start");
    }


    public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort1 = (SerialPort)sender;
        Console.WriteLine("data_recived");
        data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(data);

        pointlist_reciver();

    }

   // void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("Czas");
        // TimeSpan timeSinceStart = DateTime.Now - _startTime;
        //string output = string.Format("{0},{1}\r\n", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), (int)Math.Floor(timeSinceStart.TotalMinutes));
   //     pointlist_reciver();
   // }

    public void pointlist_reciver()

    {

                int x1;
                int y1;
                points = new List<Point>();
                string[] coordinates = new string[2];
                coordinates = data.Split(',');
                string x = coordinates[0];
                string y = coordinates[1];
                Int32.TryParse(x, out x1);
                Int32.TryParse(y, out y1);
                points.Add(new Point(x1, y1));

                if (points.Count >= 2)
                {
                     this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
                }

    }
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        PaintP(e);
    }

    public void PaintP ( PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(1500, 1500); 
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            g.Clear(Color.White);
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray()); 
        points.Clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`points.Count >= 2`

would never happen

```
this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint)
```

this does not make sense here, you need to register it only once on form load. What you are looking for is `Invalidate()`. Just beware you may be on different thread, so may need to Invoke first.

```
bmp = new Bitmap(1500, 1500); 
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    g.Clear(Color.White);
e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray()); 
points.Clear();
```

you create bitmap you do not even use. Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here.

**Example**

You have two options. Either you draw on bitmap and paste that bitmap on the form. Or you just draw on the form. I made a simple example how to use the latter option. When you move mouse on the form it draws points. Just register the eventhandlers - Load, MouseMove, Paint.

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    points.Add(e.Location);
    Invalidate();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int radius = 3;
    for (int i = points.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        Point p = points[i];

        p.Y += 1;
        if (p.Y > Height)
        {
            points.RemoveAt(i);
            continue;
        }
        points[i] = p;

        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(
            Brushes.Red,
            p.X - radius,
            p.Y - radius,
            2 * radius,
            2 * radius
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rafael I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make my code work thanks to your suggestions. It still needs some work becasue it draws seperate lines instead of continuous one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public string data;
    private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();  
    public string[] coordinates;
    private Pen pen;
    public Bitmap obrazek;
    public int i = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        obrazek = new Bitmap(1000, 1000); 
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(obrazek))
        g.Clear(Color.White); 

        SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        DoubleBuffered = true;

        pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        points = new List<Point>();

    }


    public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        SerialPort TempSerialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        //Console.WriteLine("data_recived");
        data = TempSerialPort.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        pointlist_reciver();
        //this.Invalidate();
        pictureBox2.Invalidate();



    }


    public void pointlist_reciver()

    {

        int x1;
        int y1;
        string[] coordinates = data.Split(',');
        string x = coordinates[0];
        string y = coordinates[1];
        Int32.TryParse(x, out x1);
        Int32.TryParse(y, out y1);
        points.Add(new Point(x1, y1));
        Console.WriteLine(points.Count.ToString());

    }
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(obrazek, 0, 0);

        if (points.Count >= 2)
        {

            List<Point> points2 = points.GetRange(0, 2);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(obrazek)) 
            g.DrawLines(pen, points2.ToArray());
            points.Clear();

        }
    }
 }

}
```

Later i will post final version.